# Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel error in xiaomi note 5 API 27

Tags: java, android, descriptor, parcel

My App sends 100 sms at same time.it runs perfectly in different API level but crashes on `API 27`. When i triggered my `sendSMS` method it crushes after sometimes with below error. I have searched several solution on ***SO***, but found no solution. Please give me very specific solution as i'm a novice. Sorry for my bad editing.

See image below:
[image: My error logcat]

```
  Process: co.miaki.smsbooster, PID: 6736
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors `enter code here`from parcel.
    at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
    at `enter code here`android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:804)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:742)
    at `enter code here`android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:359)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN.handleShow(Toast.java:500)
    at android.widget.Toast$TN$1.handleMessage(Toast.java:404)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6600)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at   `enter code here`com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:518)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

Comment: Sir,please post the logcat errors

Comment: i have already post it sir in image

Comment: @TaqiTahmidTanzil do you find any solution for this ?? I am getting the same error. But My scenario is I am uploading 1000 files to server.

Comment: @PankajNegi yes,i have removed Toasts from my app main thread & it solves.

Comment: ok @TaqiTahmidTanzil I will try and let you know about this. thanks for reply :)